# Proper usage of the HTML download attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would need to download a great number (2000+) of images from a website (Steam) that does not have any built-in option to do so.

(context: these are the screenshots I took over the course of approx. ten years and I'd like to have an external backup).

I have thus created a script that:

1) Retrieves the URL of each of these images HTML page (e.g. https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1808592171 );

2) Finds the URL of the image itself ( e.g. https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/798744098467952082/31C994A756957582C8AF4CA473CDD826EC0297CF/ ).

I am unable, however, to download the image itself. My approach was to have the script:

1) Find the URL of the image:

```
var picture = $(".actualmediactn a").attr("href");
```

2) Append a new link element to the body and set its href and download attributes to the value of the URL.

```
$("body").append($("<a id='xyz' target='_blank' href="+picture+" download="+picture+" ></a>"));
```

3) Click the link.

```
$('#xyz').click();
```

Doing so should theoretically download the image, but it always seem to open it in a new tab - and I cannot understand why.

Any feedback would be appreciated :)

Comment: How is this script being invoked? Are you invoking the snippet manually (i.e., in the address bar) or through some sort of browser integration, like an extension?

Comment: Hi! Browser integration - it's injected through the Tampermonkey extension (I tested it on Firefox and Chrome, with no difference in the outcome).

Comment: remove the target attrib and it should work better.

Comment: Sadly the absence or presence of the target tag doesn't seem to make any difference. Neither does having the URL after the attribute tag (e.g. download="URL" rather than just download).